# Are there any website content monitoring packages in R?

Tags: r, email, url

I know there are free website content monitoring programs that send email alerts when the content of a website is changed, but is there a package (or any way to hard code) in R which can do this?  It would be helpful to integrate this in one work flow.

Comment: what packages have you investigated and found lacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R is a *general purpose programming language* so you can do *anything* with it.

Core idiom for what you are trying to do is:

- Identify target site
- Pull content & content metadata
- Cache ^^ (you need to figure this out; RDBMS tables? NoSQL tables? Files?)
- Let `n` time-periods pass (you need to figure this out: cron? launchd? Amazon lambda?)
- Pull content & content metadata
- Compare ^^ against cached versions; NOTE this works best if you know the structure of the target site vs use an overly generic framework)
- If difference is "significant", notify via whatever means you want (you need to figure this out: email? SMS? Twitter?)

For content, you may not be aware that `httr::GET()` returns a rich, complex data object full of metadata. I did not do a `str(res)` below to encourage you to do so on your own.

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(splashr)
library(hgr) # devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/hgr")
library(tlsh) # devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/tlsh")

target_url <- "https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefings-statements/"
```

Get it like a browser would

```
httr::GET(
  url = target_url,
  httr::user_agent(splashr::ua_macos_safari)
) -> res
```

Cache page size and use a substantial difference to signal notification

```
(page_size <- res$headers['content-length'])
## $`content-length`
## [1] "12783"
```

Calculate & cache local sensitify hash value use `tlsh_simple_diff()` to see if there are "substantial" hash changes and use that as a signal to notify:

```
doc_text <- httr::content(res, as = "text")

(doc_hash <- tlsh_simple_hash(doc_text))
## [1] "563386E33C44683E060B739261ADF20CB2D38563EE151C88A3F95169999FF97A1F385D"
```

This site uses structured `<div>`'s so cache and use more/fewer/different ones to signal notification:

```
doc <- httr::content(res)

news_items <- html_nodes(doc, "div.briefing-statement__content")

(total_news_items <- length(news_items))
## [1] 10

(headlines <- gsub("[[:space:]]+", " ", html_text(news_items, trim=TRUE)))
##  [1] "News Clips CNBC: “Job Openings Hit Record 7.136 Million in August” Economy & Jobs Oct 16, 2018"                                                                            
##  [2] "Fact Sheets Congressional Democrats Want to Take Away Your Doctor, Outlaw Your Private Insurance, and Put Bureaucrats In Charge of Your Healthcare Healthcare Oct 16, 2018"
##  [3] "Remarks Remarks by President Trump in Briefing on Hurricane Michael Land & Agriculture Oct 15, 2018"                                                                       
##  [4] "Remarks Remarks by President Trump and Governor Scott at FEMA Aid Distribution Center | Lynn Haven, FL Land & Agriculture Oct 15, 2018"                                    
##  [5] "Remarks Remarks by President Trump During Tour of Lynn Haven Community | Lynn Haven, FL Land & Agriculture Oct 15, 2018"                                                   
##  [6] "Remarks Remarks by President Trump and Governor Scott Upon Arrival in Florida Land & Agriculture Oct 15, 2018"                                                             
##  [7] "Remarks Remarks by President Trump Before Marine One Departure Foreign Policy Oct 15, 2018"                                                                                
##  [8] "Statements & Releases White House Appoints 2018-2019 Class of White House Fellows Oct 15, 2018"                                                                            
##  [9] "Statements & Releases President Donald J. Trump Approves Georgia Disaster Declaration Land & Agriculture Oct 14, 2018"                                                     
## [10] "Statements & Releases President Donald J. Trump Amends Florida Disaster Declaration Land & Agriculture Oct 14, 2018"
```

Use a "readability" tool to turn the contents into plaintext cache & compare with one of the many "text diff/string diff" R packages:

```
content_meta <- hgr::just_the_facts(target_url)

str(content_meta)
## List of 11
##  $ title         : chr "Briefings & Statements"
##  $ content       : chr "<p class=\"body-overflow\"> <header class=\"header\"> </header>\n<main id=\"main-content\"> <div class=\"page-r"| __truncated__
##  $ lead_image_url: chr "https://www.whitehouse.gov/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/wh.gov-share-img_03-1024x538.png"
##  $ next_page_url : chr "https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefings-statements/page/2"
##  $ url           : chr "https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefings-statements/"
##  $ domain        : chr "www.whitehouse.gov"
##  $ excerpt       : chr "Get official White House briefings, statements, and remarks from President Donald J. Trump and members of his Administration."
##  $ word_count    : int 22
##  $ direction     : chr "ltr"
##  $ total_pages   : int 2
##  $ pages_rendered: int 2
##  - attr(*, "row.names")= int 1
##  - attr(*, "class")= chr "hgr"
```

Unfortunately, you asked a general purpose computing-ish question and, as such, it is likely to get closed.

Comment: Huh. https://pastebin.com/zTrYanr3 appeared a cpl minutes after posting ^^. SO is sure a strange place this year.

Comment: that's OK, thanks for your answer, it's most helpful!

Comment: Cool. The pastebin comment was that someone cut/paste the disparate code-divs into a pastebin. Been seeing that more lately and am wondering if there's a browser extension for that